# Menu issue with safari 5

Tags: css, safari

I have a problem with safari 5 moving images around. Originally I thought it was just in Safari for windows, but intact it's in all of safari 5.
The list items that have dropdown menu seem to drop down ok, and then the img at the top of the list jumps down to the bottom of the list covering the bottom two list items.

Can anyone help?
I have taken out as much extra code (such as mouse over events) as possible but the problem persists

[the page with the problem](http://www.playlistforlife.org.uk/test/index.html)

and here's the CSS where I suspect the problem with safari is:

```
    #nav,#nav ul {
font-family:verdana;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
position:relative;


}      
#nav {
height:50px;
width: 800px ;
margin-left: auto ;
margin-right: auto ;
overflow:hidden;
top:0;

}  
#nav li {
float:left;
position:relative;
z-index:10;
}
#nav li a {
background:url(../images/bg-menu.png) no-repeat center top;
color:#000;
display:block;
float:left;
font-size:14px;
height:51px;
line-height:40px;
padding:0 10px;
position:relative;
text-decoration:none;
z-index:20;
}
/* Left end padding*/
#nav li:first-child a {
background:url(../images/bg-menu.png) no-repeat left top;
padding-left:45px;
}
#nav li ul li:first-child a {
background-image:none;
padding-left:10px;
}

/* Right end padding*/
#nav li.pad {
background:url(../images/bg-menu.png) no-repeat right top;
display:block;
height:51px;
width:15px;
}
#nav ul {
background:#FFFFFF;
height:auto;
padding:10px 0;
position:absolute;
top:-125px;
width:180px;
z-index:-1;

transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-ms-box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-moz-transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:0.8s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:all 0.8s ease-in-out;
}
#nav ul li {
width:180px;

}
#nav ul li a {
background:transparent;
height:20px;
line-height:20px;
width:180px;
}
#nav:hover {
height:200px;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
transform:translate(0,161px);
-moz-transform:translate(0,161px); /*some css3*/
-o-transform:translate(0,161px);
-webkit-transform:translate(0,161px);
-ms-transform:translate(0,161px);
}
#nav a:hover,#nav li:hover > a {
color:#6d6e71;
}
.rslides {
  position: relative;
 list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
  }

.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

.rslides li:first-child {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

.rslides img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;    
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Describe in more detail what you mean by moving images around?

Comment: I've added more info on how they move around above. Sorry - I'm really new here - How do I best provide a fiddle?

Comment: @PeterKirkwood You would show us a reduced test case using a tool like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @OllyHodgson -thanks! As I cut stuff out to give a reduced test case it started to work. I'll start adding stuff back in, and that should tell me where the problem is... I'll setup the case on jsfiddle.net if i can't work it out. Thanks again

Comment: Typical! Hope it works out :)

Comment: @OllyHodgson - OK - I think I have narrowed it down to it being a problem between the slider and the menu - possible as they both use <li> and <ul> tags - I've added the slider css above. So far I haven't been able to work out jsfiddle tho! Do you have any ideas with the extra css added above? Sorry! Thanks!